# Can autoencoders be used for reconstructing non-binary vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I've recently learned about auto-encoders and plan to construct one to use as part of a recommender system with implicit feedback.

Based on how classic autoencoders works, it seems like they can be used for reconstructing vectors whose components are not necessarily 0 or 1. However, all introductory materials out there seem to suggest that autoencoders operate on binary vectors, **x**=[0,1]^d, as in [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html), or section 2.2 in this [paper](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vincentp/Publications/denoising_autoencoders_tr1316.pdf).

In order to use autoencoders for non-binary vectors, it seems to me that the only difference is that L2 error function should be used instead of crossentropy which is suitable for binary cases.

I appreciate if someone can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the notation

```
x e [0, 1]^d
```

means "x belongs to the space being a d-dimensional unit hypercube". To say "x is a binary vector of length d" you would write

```
x e {0, 1}^d
```

Notice different brackets. `[0, 1]` is **an interval**, not a set of 2 elements.

Thus **noone is claiming that autoencoder requires binary input**, and **it does not**, it is defined in the whole R^d space (however for various reasons it is easier to work with valued from some limited subset, thus [0, 1] hypercube, for which we have quite good heuristics for initialization).